# docx vs. old Word .xml file - where did wx:sect and wx:sub-section go?

Tags: xml, ms-word, docx

I have Word to HTML transforms for over a decade they were built on the old Word 2003 XML format. Now moving to .docx it is not very hard overall, because the xmlns:w and the xmlns:v schemas are largely the same even if the xmlns:w namespace URI has changed. But one thing I just cannot find and that is the wx:sect and wx:sub-section elements. They were very helpful to me as I would transform them to HTML div elements.

I searched for sect and sub-section in the entire unzipped .docx tree but cannot find. I know I *could* structurize it based on the style names, but it is a lot of extra work. So hoping I had just overlooked the corresponding annotation/markup?

Comment: Those are different formats that share many features, but are not identical. If you do a save as and save a .docx with sections as _Word 2003 XML Document (*.xml)_, voila! wx:sect is part of that file.

Comment: Yes, I know word puts these back. My question was if they have really no representation in the docx bundle.

Answer (score 2):

wx:sect and wx:subsection tags have been removed from the spec. The rest of the XML structure is very similar. I created a simple document with a single section break. In a .docx file, it looks like this:

```
<w:body>
    <w:p w14:paraId="55E1DD0B" w14:textId="754A9065" w:rsidR="00A934F5" w:rsidRDefault="00A934F5" w:rsidP="00857546"/>
    <w:p w14:paraId="0AA91CED" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00701B63" w:rsidRDefault="00701B63" w:rsidP="00857546">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00701B63" w:rsidSect="00512022">
                <w:headerReference w:type="even" r:id="rId6"/>
                <w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId7"/>
                <w:footerReference w:type="even" r:id="rId8"/>
                <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId9"/>
                <w:headerReference w:type="first" r:id="rId10"/>
                <w:footerReference w:type="first" r:id="rId11"/>
                <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" w:code="1"/>
                <w:pgMar w:top="720" w:right="720" w:bottom="720" w:left="720" w:header="360" w:footer="360" w:gutter="0"/>
                <w:cols w:space="720"/>
                <w:titlePg/>
                <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
            </w:sectPr>
        </w:pPr>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w14:paraId="48926183" w14:textId="31B1BCEA" w:rsidR="00701B63" w:rsidRDefault="00701B63" w:rsidP="00857546"/>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00701B63" w:rsidSect="00701B63">
        <w:type w:val="continuous"/>
        <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" w:code="1"/>
        <w:pgMar w:top="720" w:right="720" w:bottom="720" w:left="720" w:header="360" w:footer="360" w:gutter="0"/>
        <w:cols w:space="720"/>
        <w:titlePg/>
        <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
</w:body>
```

In a Word 2003 XML file, it looks like this:

```
<w:body>
    <wx:sect>
        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00A934F5" wsp:rsidRDefault="00A934F5" wsp:rsidP="00857546"/>
        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00701B63" wsp:rsidRDefault="00701B63" wsp:rsidP="00857546">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:sectPr wsp:rsidR="00701B63" wsp:rsidSect="00512022">
                    <w:hdr w:type="even">
                        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00023B1B" wsp:rsidRDefault="00023B1B">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:pStyle w:val="Header"/>
                            </w:pPr>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:hdr>
                    <w:hdr w:type="odd">
                        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00023B1B" wsp:rsidRDefault="00023B1B">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:pStyle w:val="Header"/>
                            </w:pPr>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:hdr>
                    <w:ftr w:type="even">
                        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00023B1B" wsp:rsidRDefault="00023B1B">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:pStyle w:val="Footer"/>
                            </w:pPr>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:ftr>
                    <w:ftr w:type="odd">
                        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00023B1B" wsp:rsidRDefault="00023B1B">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:pStyle w:val="Footer"/>
                            </w:pPr>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:ftr>
                    <w:hdr w:type="first">
                        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00023B1B" wsp:rsidRDefault="00023B1B" wsp:rsidP="00857546">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:pStyle w:val="Header"/>
                            </w:pPr>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:hdr>
                    <w:ftr w:type="first">
                        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00023B1B" wsp:rsidRDefault="00023B1B" wsp:rsidP="00857546"/>
                    </w:ftr>
                    <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" w:code="1"/>
                    <w:pgMar w:top="720" w:right="720" w:bottom="720" w:left="720" w:header="360" w:footer="360" w:gutter="0"/>
                    <w:cols w:space="720"/>
                    <w:titlePg/>
                    <w:docGrid w:line-pitch="360"/>
                </w:sectPr>
            </w:pPr>
        </w:p>
    </wx:sect>
    <wx:sect>
        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00701B63" wsp:rsidRDefault="00701B63" wsp:rsidP="00857546"/>
        <w:sectPr wsp:rsidR="00701B63" wsp:rsidSect="00701B63">
            <w:type w:val="continuous"/>
            <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" w:code="1"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="720" w:right="720" w:bottom="720" w:left="720" w:header="360" w:footer="360" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="720"/>
            <w:titlePg/>
            <w:docGrid w:line-pitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </wx:sect>
</w:body>
```

It appears the programmers realized they didn't need an separate tag to denote the start and end of a section, so they took it out.

Comment: I think there is a difference between "section" where your page format headers, footers, etc. change and the section and sub-section which is created by the header outline structure. I think it is actually rather hard to generate the wx:sub-section tags. Not impossible, just a real loss not to have them any more.